# What is the correct location to put PHP files for connecting with a MySQL databsae

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have set up a database on a hosting site and want to connect it with my Android app. I am following this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

The tutorial doesn't say where you should save the Php files that are created, so where should I be saving them using the file manager in Cpanel?
the current structure looks like this:

[image: A image of folder structure]

Comment: yes you need place inside the public_html if you want to call that file means yourdomainname/filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php files must upload to "public_html" folder to view public.

for example: if your domain is: http://example.com/ you must create "index.php" file in "public_html" folder, so you can access that by: http://example.com/index.php or http://example.com/

read more, how using cpanel: 
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/file_manager.htm

Comment: Hi, the php files that I am using output data from a database, so I am assuming that unless anyone had the specific url for that particular .php file it would be difficult to find it? also, should you create a sub-folder in the  "public_html" folder like a "php" folder to store the different php pages? thanks for your answer

Comment: yes and yes. for more seure save your cdes in "mycode23478264786.php" a random number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your codes to the root folder, which in your case is public_html